# Как создать "древовидные" массивы в JSON?

Tags: java, json

Я понимаю как "распарсить" строку json в которой есть древовидная структура, но не могу понять, как создать дополнительные массивы в определенной ветке.
Ниже пример структуры, которую мне нужно создать программно. Приведите пожалуйста пример хотя бы некоторых ветвей.

```
{
    "update": "20170101000230",
    "create": "20170101000230",
    "id": "20170511232754063740_1939324677",
    "items": [
      {
      "id": "0_0",
      "name": "name 0_0",
      "type": "M",
      "comm":"комментарий",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "1_0",
          "name": "name 1_0",
          "type": "M",
        },
        {
          "id": "1_1",
          "name": "name 1_1",
          "type": "M",
          "jd": "240000"
        },
        {
          "id": "1_3",
          "name": "name 1_3",
          "type": "M",
          "jd": "240000",
          "items": {
            "id": "2_0",
            "name": "name 2_0",
            "type": "M",
            "jd": "240000",
            "items": {
              "id": "3_0",
              "name": "name 3_0",
              "type": "M",
              "jd": "240000"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "0_1",
      "name": "name 0_1",
      "type": "M",
      "jd": "240000",
      "cityid":"4000",
      "comm":"комментарий",
      "city":"SPb"
    },
    {
      "id": "0_2",
      "name": "name 0_2",
      "type": "M",
      "cityid":"4000",
      "comm":"комментарий",
    },
    {
      "id": "0_3",
      "name": "name 0_3",
      "type": "M",
      "jd": "240000",
      "comm":"комментарий",
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, можно сначала создавать дочерние элементы и потом вставлять их в родительские.

Простой пример:

```
JSONObject thirdLevelJsonObject = new JSONObject();
thirdLevelJsonObject.put("name", "json_object");
thirdLevelJsonObject.put("level", 3);

JSONObject secondLevelJsonObject = new JSONObject();
secondLevelJsonObject.put("name", "json_object");
secondLevelJsonObject.put("level", 2);
secondLevelJsonObject.put("content", thirdLevelJsonObject);

JSONObject firstLevelJsonObject = new JSONObject();
firstLevelJsonObject.put("name", "json_object");
firstLevelJsonObject.put("level", 1);
firstLevelJsonObject.put("content", secondLevelJsonObject);
```

В итоге, `firstLevelJsonObject` будет таким:

```
{  
   "name":"json_object",
   "level":1,
   "content":{  
      "name":"json_object",
      "level":2,
      "content":{  
         "name":"json_object",
         "level":3
      }
   }
}
```